# why do i have to re-size JFrame to see the component

Tags: java, swing, jframe

i have a small problem the component in the JFrame are not showing until i re-size the frame then all component are visible there are something is missing i don't know where can any one tell me where is the problem

```
import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
    import javax.swing.JTable;
    import javax.swing.JToolBar;
    import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;

    /**
     *
     * @author isslam
     */
    public class swingInterface extends JFrame{
        JToolBar bar;
        //toolbar button
        JButton openButton,exitButton;
        JTable table;
        public swingInterface(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(500,500);
        frame.setLocation(400, 100);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         // declration of bar
        bar = new JToolBar("still dragble");

        openButton = new JButton();
        exitButton = new JButton();
        openButton.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/res/open-file-icon.png")));
        exitButton.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/res/logout-icon.png")));
        bar.add(openButton);
        bar.add(exitButton);
        //panel for jtable
        String[] columnNames = {"First Name",
                            "Last Name",
                            "Sport",
                            "# of Years",
                            "Vegetarian"};
        Object[][] data = {
        {"Kathy", "Smith",
         "Snowboarding", new Integer(5), new Boolean(false)},
        {"John", "Doe",
         "Rowing", new Integer(3), new Boolean(true)},
        {"Sue", "Black",
         "Knitting", new Integer(2), new Boolean(false)},
        {"Jane", "White",
         "Speed reading", new Integer(20), new Boolean(true)},
        {"Joe", "Brown",
         "Pool", new Integer(10), new Boolean(false)}
    };
        table = new JTable(data,columnNames);
        JScrollPane spanel = new  JScrollPane(table);
        TitledBorder titled = new TitledBorder("Title");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.setBorder(titled); 
        panel.setBackground(pink);
         panel.add(spanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);


         frame.add(bar,BorderLayout.NORTH);
         frame.add(panel,BorderLayout.CENTER);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Because you're setting it visible before all components are added.  Notes: 1) Call `pack()` after components are added and before `setVisible(true)` 2) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example). 3) One way to get image(s) for an example is to hot link to images seen in [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19209650/418556).

Comment: thank u now i am reading SSCCE and it work for me now

Comment: Glad you got it sorted.  :)

Comment: FYI Swing is lazy, this is intentionally, as it makes it faster. This allows you to make a number of modifications, quickly and the post a single update when you're ready, instead of Swing trying to makes updates on each add/remove

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling your frame's `setVisible(true)` method before you add all of the desired components to it. Move the call to the end of your constructor.

```
public swinginterface {
    // adding components to the JFrame
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: *"`frame.setVisible(true)` should be called once you are finished adding all of the desired components to it."*  This is not strictly correct.  Components **can** be added to a GUI after it has become visible, they just require special handling.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I know. It's just that I wrote this answer in reference to OP's issue.

Comment: I understand that, but it is still wrong information.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Is this a better answer?

Comment: Yes.  Now that the implication that that is the only way to do it has been removed, it is now correct information.